# Windows named pipe partial read

Tags: windows, winapi, named-pipes

Is such situation possible when I read pipe via ReadFile and it returns me partial data, causing me to call ReadFile again until specified number of bytes read is reached?

Comment: yes, such situation possible.

Comment: if `PIPE_TYPE_BYTE`|`PIPE_READMODE_BYTE` yes. if `PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE + PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE` no

Comment: Thanks, my life became easier )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`PIPE_TYPE_BYTE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createnamedpipea) is set at side which create the named pipe.

At reading side, set [`PIPE_READMODE_BYTE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/namedpipeapi/nf-namedpipeapi-setnamedpipehandlestate) mode for reading partial data.

In partial reading mode, you can use `PIPE_READMODE_BYTE` and `PIPE_NOWAIT` combination to avoid the `ReadFile` function hangs. [`lpNumberOfBytesRead`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile) parameter can be used to detect if there is more data to read. When there is no data to be read the `lpNumberOfBytesRead` will be zero if the `ReadFile` function call success. Otherwise, check the error by calling the GetLastError function.

Based on official sample: [Named Pipe Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/named-pipe-client) and [Multithreaded Pipe Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/multithreaded-pipe-server).

The client reading related code will be change to:

```
dwMode = PIPE_READMODE_BYTE | PIPE_NOWAIT;// PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE;
fSuccess = SetNamedPipeHandleState(
    hPipe,    // pipe handle 
    &dwMode,  // new pipe mode 
    NULL,     // don't set maximum bytes 
    NULL);    // don't set maximum time 

// ...

WCHAR rdWChar;
do
{
    // Read from the pipe. 

    fSuccess = ReadFile(
        hPipe,    // pipe handle 
        &rdWChar,  // buffer to receive reply 
        2,        // test size, read two bytes per read operation
        &cbRead,  // number of bytes read 
        NULL);    // not overlapped 

    if (!fSuccess && GetLastError() != ERROR_MORE_DATA)
        break;

    wprintf(L"%c", rdWChar);
} while (cbRead); // repeat loop if there is more bytes
```